# Need Help with Validation Rule(s) on Stage Changes

Tags: reporting, formula, validation, lookup

Need help with validation rules:
Just found out our salespeople are not required to move their opportunities stage by stage. In other words, they can go from ‘Set Meeting’ to ‘Negotiation’ and bypass the other stages (see below matrix).  Based on the matrix below, can you help me with the validation rules? Do I have to create several rules or use “OR” statements?

Note: the check marks mean at that stage a revenue/forecast amount is required.

The only stages we need validation rules begin with “Term Sheet Out” to “Sold / Shipped”.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it generally depends on whether or not you want to have an individualized "Error message" for the validation rules. To restrict the user, you can use both OR statements or separate validation rules. But you'd have to use a more general error text, which would be either be too long to read (if you write the whole set of rules to the error message) or would not tell the user what is expected from him (if you write some short general message). 
I would go for separate rules and more descriptive error message.

Regards,
Tomas

Comment: HI Tomas - I agree with you about creating seperate rules with descriptive error messages. Can you help me write the validation rules based on the matrix above? Thanks

Comment: Sure. The key to Validation rules is, that when the rule evaluates to true, the record will NOT be saved. So, if I understand the specifics of your case (that you need the stage to go one after another), the formula of one of the rules we talk about could look like this `AND( ISPICKVAL( StageName , "Negotiation") , NOT( ISPICKVAL( PRIORVALUE(StageName) , "Term Sheet Out") ))`. This rule will deny switch to "Negotiation" from any stage with exception of "Term Sheet Out" The other rules would follow the same pattern.

Comment: Thanks @Tomas - Our salespeople are not forced to move opportunities stage by stage. For example - an opportunity can go from "Set Meeting" to "Term Sheet Out" or "Negotiation".

Comment: So the validation rules would begin when "Term Sheet Out" is selected and saved - Potential amount would be required. Same with the other stages below it. "Negotiation" must have EITHER Potential or Probable or both and "Closed Won" must have Confirmed and can have Proabable.

Answer (score 1):

As a potential alternative, you could use a combination of workflow rules and record types to force users to go from one stage to the next in sequence. This has more "lead time" involved (more complicated than validation rules), but enforces a strict set of UI changes that occur from stage to stage.

Based on your matrix, you might have the following record types:

Pipeline
Potential
Probable
Confirmed

Each record type would have a "Sales Process" by the same name. Pipeline would include Set Meeting, Meeting Held, Term Sheet Out, and Closed Lost, Potential would include Term Sheet Out, Negotiation, and Closed Lost, etc.

A workflow rule would check if the stage is set to Term Sheet Out, then change the record type on the opportunity from Pipeline to Potential. The user becomes "locked out" of changing to any prior status, or skipping past Negotiation. You can include earlier values if you want to give the user the ability to revert back to a prior stage, but you'll probably leave this just for management or administrators to fix "accidents."

You can have a different page layout for the Potential Record Type from the Pipeline Record Type. This means you can show or hide fields, make some fields read-only or required, etc. The user wouldn't be able to progress to Negotiation until all the required fields for Term Sheet Out have been filled in.

A second workflow rule would check for "stage is Negotiation" and change the record type to "Probable." You can configure this step independently as well. Repeat the process for the Confirmed record type, and you'll be set.

I estimate that the effort would be about an hour or so, as opposed to a few minutes using a validation rule, but the user wouldn't be stumbling around in the dark, as each phase would automatically present itself to the user as they progress instead of a myriad of error messages.